# optimal method of elixir map bindings

Tags: elixir

I have the following code:

```
    total_pages = res["payload"]["total pages"]
    current_page = res["payload"]["page"]
    total_entities = res["payload"]["total entities"]
    queryId = res["payload"]["queryId"]
    unprocessed_entities = res["payload"]["entities"]
```

where `res` is a http response map. What is the Elixir way of binding these values?

Comment: Define “binding” please. Why would you need a bunch of local variables in the first place?

Comment: What I meant was 'matching' rather than 'binding'. Local variables because I'll be referencing them at later stages, where I'd rather not be reaching into the map. Also, I think it's better to be explicit with what I'm referencing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pattern match directly on everything you need:

```
%{
    "payload" => %{
        "total pages" => total_pages,
        "page" => current_page,
        "total entities" => total_entities,
        "queryId" => queryId,
        "entities" => unprocessed_entities
    }
} = res
```

Comment: Please note that is not an exact equivalent of direct assignment as in the question. If the `res["payload"]` map _does not have any of the keys_, `foo = res["payload"]["foo"]` would assign `nil` to the `foo` local variable, while this code will raise.

Comment: Thanks for making this distinction. Since I need the response payload to contain all these key-value pairs, it's actually quite convenient that it'll raise an exception, which I'll need to handle.

Comment: You should not handle exceptions in Elixir in general, this is kinda anti-pattern in 99% of cases. Please update the question with what are you exactly after. This answer completely covers what you have asked, but it looks like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to ensure that the response payload have all these keys and handle the failure in a different way, you might use the function with different clauses:

```rb
defp local_vars(
  %{
    "total pages" => tp,
    "page" => cp,
    "total entities" => te,
    "queryId" => qid,
    "entities" => ue
   }), do: {:ok, {tp, cp, te, qid, ue}}
defp local_vars(_), do: {:error, :bad_payload}
```

and call it from your code like

```rb
case local_vars(res["payload"]) do
  {:ok, {total_pages, current_page,
         total_entities, query_id,
         unprocessed_entities}} ->
     # here you have all the local variables bound
  {:error, reason} -> IO.puts("Failed with reason #{reason}")
end
```

---

Or, simply do all the work inside the successful clause, then you would not need `case`.